# sql select statement with field having multiple values

Tags: abap, opensql

I have few check-boxes on my selection screen. Each check-box corresponds to a value which a field of a table can take. I have to then fire a select query where a particular field of a table can have all values whose corresponding check-box is selected.

Suppose I have 5 check-box corresponding to values a1-a5.
Now if check-boxes 1, 3, and 4 are checked then the field of the table can have values a1 or a3 or a4.

```
select * from table where field = a1 or field = a2 or field = a3.
```

One way to do this is creating 5 variables and then doing something like this

```
if checkbox1 checked
  then var1 = a1
else
  var1 = '0'    //something which would never occur in the field of the table
```

and so on for all check-boxes.

And then

```
select * from table where field = var1 or field = var2 or field = var3 or field = var4 or field = var5.
```

This becomes difficult if there are 15 check-boxes.
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Try IN ; `where field IN (var1, var2, var3, ....)`. You still need to build the list inside IN but might be easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [select-option/range table](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_750/en/ABAPTYPES_RANGES.htm) for this:

```
DATA field_range TYPE RANGE OF data_type_of_table_field.

IF p_check1 = abap_true.
  field_range = VALUE #( BASE field_range ( sign = 'I' option = 'EQ' low = 'A1' ) ).
ENDIF.
IF p_check2 = abap_true.
  field_range = VALUE #( BASE field_range ( sign = 'I' option = 'EQ' low = 'A2' ) ).
ENDIF.
" ...

SELECT whatever FROM wherever WHERE field IN field_range.
```

**CAUTION:** An empty range table will match anything ("no restrictions") and fetch the entire contents of the database table, so you'll usually need to check for this separately.

Comment: Nice usage of the new syntax. +1 Has the `BASE` keyword been introduced lately? I get a syntax error on my system.

Comment: @Jagger Try `BASE field_range[]`- but other than that, I think it's been there all the time with the new syntax...

Comment: I have a co-worker, who experienced a dump if the entries in the ranges table ( I/EQ ) exceed some certain amount. Someone else in here, too ?

Comment: @icbytes It happens because the produced SQL exceeds the buffer and the cutted instruction is executed. It has happened to me in the past.

Comment: @vwegert The `BASE` keyword has been added in SP08 of 7.40. More info [here](http://scn.sap.com/community/abap/blog/2014/10/13/abap-language-news-for-release-740-sp08). Too bad I have to work with SP06. ;)

Comment: For new comers who do not understand `VALUE #( ...)`: https://blogs.sap.com/2013/05/27/abap-news-for-release-740-constructor-operator-value/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
select * from table where field IN (a1,a2,a3 ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

one possible way: append checked values to an internal table and then use FOR ALL ENTRIES in select statement.